# Наследование в Delphi. Правильность конструкции.

Tags: наследование, ооп, delphi

Добрый день!
Сегодня помогал одногруппнику с дипломной работой, и заметил у него следующую конструкцию:
он создает свой собственный класс типа `TStringGrid` (назовем его `TMYStringGrid`), описывает его методы, свойства, ну все, как полагается. НО он использует в программе не потомки этого класса, а элементы `TStringGrid`, и обращается этими стринггридами к методам своего собственного класса.
Пример кода:

```
// описание класса
type TMyStringGrid = class (TstringGrid)
  private
  protected
  public
    procedure MyProc;
end;

//использование его методов
procedure bla_bla_bla;
begin
...
  TMyStringGrid(StringGrid1).MyProc; // где StringGrid1 ребенок TStringGrid
...
end;
```

Можно так делать или это нежелательно? Если нежелательно, то почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это совершенно правильный и рабочий хак для быстрого расширения существующих классов (до появления class helpers). Если не приводить левые указатели к TMyStringGrid, то совершенно безопасно.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше этого не делать. Могут возникнуть непредвиденные ошибки. Например, если не будет существовать класс TStringGrid, то программа станет неработоспособной. Хотя, если планируется запустить однажды в той же системе, где и был написан класс, то ничего страшного возникнуть не должно. Ведь(к примеру) к классу TStringList часто обращаются из других классов.

Comment: Делать так можно, только осторожно (не добавляя новых полей, например). *Если не будет существовать класс TStringGrid, то программа станет неработоспособной* - заблуждение. Класс описан в VCL и в скомпилированной программе существует всегда (или в библиотеках, без которых программа и так не запустится).

Answer (score -1):

Теоретически нельзя, но. Если delphi этого не ловит, значит можно. Если бы рантайм контролировал типы поаккуратней, то получили бы облом. В других языках может не пройти.

Comment: Наследование от класса и приведение указателя к классу в Делфи вполне разрешено. Не вводите людей в заблуждение )